# Spring MVC - Serving Content Twice

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc

I've been looking for a week for some guidance on how to server content to my webpage ***twice because severing content once works, with Model or ModelAndView but if a user interacts with the page again I want it to load more content on SAME PAGE.

Java Spring back-end methods Get works Post doesn't:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "explorer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectExplorer(@RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String name, Model model) {
    if (name != null) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
        OffenderDAO offenderDAO = (OffenderDAO) context.getBean("offenderDAO");
        Offender[] offenders = null;
        try {
            offenders = offenderDAO.requestOffenders(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
        model.addAttribute("offenderlists", offenders);
    }
    return "explorer";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "explorer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String selectionHandler(@RequestParam("offenderid") String text, Model map) {
    String offenderID = text.trim();
    System.out.println("requested more info for: " + offenderID);
    Offender offender = null;
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
    OffenderDAO offenderDAO = (OffenderDAO) context.getBean("offenderDAO");
    try {
        offender = offenderDAO.findOffenderById(offenderID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
    map.addAttribute("selectedOffender", offender);
    return "explorer";
}
```

Ok so as you can see the GET method loads a list which the user can interact with and that will send a post response to the other method shown. The issue is that even though the post is received and the data is present in the response back(confirmed by println) the webpage doesn't update.

Here is the JSP code responsible for the above model changes.

```
<ul class="result-class">
            <c:forEach var="offender" items="${offenderlists}">
                <li><div class="result-div">
                        <div class="result-img-holder">
                            <img class="lazy" src=<c:out value="${offender.linkToPicture}"/>
                                height="120" width="120" /> <span class=result-div-titles>
                                OffenderID: </span>
                            <c:out value="${offender.offenderId}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="result-div-oinfo">
                            <ul class="info-list1">
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> First Name: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.firstName}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Last Name: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.lastName}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Middle Name: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.middleName}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> DOB: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.DOB}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Sex: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.sex}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Risk Level: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.riskLevel}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Designation: </span> <c:out
                                        value="${offender.designation}" /></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="info-list2">
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Race: </span>
                                <c:out value="${offender.race}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Ethnicity: </span>
                                <c:out value="${offender.ethnicity}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Hair Color: </span>
                                <c:out value="${offender.hairColor}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Eye Color: </span>
                                <c:out value="${offender.eyeColor}" /></li>
                                <li><span class=result-div-titles> Glasses: </span>
                                <c:out value="${offender.correctiveLens}" /></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="result-address">
                                <span class=result-div-titles> Primary Address: </span><br>
                                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.address_line1}" />
                                <br>
                                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.city}" />
                                , New York
                                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.zipcode}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>


<div id="wide-sidebar">
            First Name: <c:out value="${selectedOffender.firstName}"/>
            <div id="vehicles-sidebar">
                <h1>Vehicles Registered:</h1>
                <ul>
                    <c:forEach  items="${selectedOffender.currentVehicles}" var="vehicle">
                        <li>
                        <span><c:out value="${vehicle.plate}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;">something1<c:out value="${vehicle.state}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.color}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.make}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.model}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.year}"/></span></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Problem recap**
I have two lists that load seperate of each other based on user interaction on one page. One list loads but the other will not. It's not the code I am just missing something... There are no errors

**Goal**
The goal here is to load a list of choices from a database and then the user can choose a choice which loads another half of the webpage. But note the problem is that the choices load fine but not the rest of webpage. If I load the rest of the webpage first it works but then the list will not load when requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to make a new JSP and use an iframe... idea inspired by spotify web player lol ;)

Here is how I used an Iframe

```
<iframe src="wideSidebar" id = "wide-sidebar"></iframe> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.result-div').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(200);
            var text1 = $(this).parent().text().split(":")[1].split("\n")[1];
            $("#wide-sidebar").attr("src", "wideSidebar?id="+text1);
            $("#wide-sidebar").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
</script>
@RequestMapping(value = "wideSidebar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSideBar(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String name) {
        ModelAndView map = new ModelAndView("wideSidebar");
        if (name != null) {
            String offenderID = name.trim();
            System.out.println("requested more info for: " + offenderID);
            Offender offender = null;
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
            OffenderDAO offenderDAO = (OffenderDAO) context.getBean("offenderDAO");
            try {
                offender = offenderDAO.findOffenderById(offenderID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
            map.addObject("selected", offender);
        }
        return map;
    }

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
First Name: <c:out value="${selected.firstName}"/>
            <div id="vehicles-sidebar">
                <h1>Vehicles Registered:</h1>
                <ul>
                    <c:forEach  items="${selected.currentVehicles}" var="vehicle">
                        <li>
                        <span><c:out value="${vehicle.plate}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.state}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.color}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.make}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.model}"/></span>
                        <span style="margin:10px;"><c:out value="${vehicle.year}"/></span></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```